# JavaScript seedable Math.random

Tags: javascript, random

I made an implementation of xoshiro256** in JavaScript, using BigInts. It's designed to mimic Math.random. Any feedback on the code quality?

```javascript
function rol64(x, k) {
    return (x << k) | (x >> (64n - k));
}
// state is an array of BigInts that are unsigned 64-bit integers
// you could use a normal array, or a BigUint64Array
function xoshiro256ss(state) {
    return function() {
        const result = rol64(state[1] * 5n, 7n) * 9n;
        const t = state[1] << 17n;
        state[2] ^= state[0];
        state[3] ^= state[1];
        state[1] ^= state[2];
        state[0] ^= state[3];
        state[2] ^= t;
        state[3] = rol64(state[3], 45n);
        return Number(BigInt.asUintN(53, result)) / (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1);
    }
}

// example usage (browser)
const random = xoshiro256ss(
    crypto.getRandomValues(new BigUint64Array(4))
);

alert(random());
```

Comment: what is `n` in `rol64(state[1] * 5 n, 7 n) * 9 n`

Comment: @depperm The "n" in front of a number denotes a BigInt, an integer value in JavaScript which can hold numbers of any length. Since JavaScript can only represent integers up to (2^53) - 1 accurately (because it uses IEEE 754 doubles as its number type), I needed to use BigInts to work with 64-bit unsigned integers. So the numbers are just 5, 7, and 9.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not ship this code as-is.

---

The identifier `xoshiro256ss` is apparently intended to denote
[xoshiro256**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xoshiro256%2A%2A),
but there is no comment or documentation explaining that.
You should definitely cite a reference,
even if only Wikipedia.

The comment "`state` is an array of [non-negative] BigInts"
is pretty clear, thank you for that.
The assumption is never verified.
It seems pretty easy for a caller to accidentally
mis-use the Public API and never notice the mistake,
for example by passing in ordinary integers or floats.

This submission contains no unit tests.
As such, it does not instill confidence that it
correctly computes what the spec asks of it.

Comparing the behavior of a C implementation
with this implementation, on diverse inputs,
would be of interest.
There are a few edge case inputs that would be
especially interesting.

The named spec is all about stirring 256 bits of entropy.
Yet we return a number between zero and one like Math.random,
rather than 64 high-entropy bits.
That detail really needs to be called out in the Public API
documentation or comments.
It looks like we cannot return 2^64 distinct values as promised by the spec.

---

This code does not detect the user error
of supplying an all-zeros state vector.
Repeatedly asking for random numbers
will yield decidedly non-random output
if `state` ever stores just 256 zeros.

---

My understanding is we should have the following invariant:

> Elements of `state[]` shall at all times be non-negative integers that are at most 2^64 - 1.

Yet I see this:

```
        const t = state[1] << 17n;
```

I *think* that in the spec we should see
seventeen low-order bits cleared to zero,
and we should see an integer less than 2^64.
But the BigInt `t` apparently retains
high order bits and can exceed 2^64 ?!?

```
    s[2] ^= t;
```

Later on the XOR will set high-order bits in this element,
and from there they will propagate to all other elements.
I am hard pressed to see how this JS code
implements the original algorithm.

Why are you even asking a human if this code
computes what it is supposed to?
Ask the machine.
You have other implementations available.
Ask if they mutate `state` in the same way.

---

Another invariant is that `state` shall always
store 256 bits.

But it appears to me that a loop which keeps
asking for new numbers will cause storage
to grow without bound.

---

Improve the automated testing and documentation before merging down to `main`.

Comment: The results differ from the C version on the author's web-site, so I'll have to take a look at that. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: They differed because in the C version, the results are wrapped around (due to the uint64_t), while in the JS version the results are not wrapped around because the BigInt can fit it. Simply turning it into a 64-bit unsigned integer via `BigInt.asUintN` returns the same results as the C version.

Comment: That was an expensive thing to learn. Write it down in the codebase, so that running automated tests will detect regression.